# Debug of data transmission via I2C

Tags: pic, i2c

I was able to generate I<sup>2</sup>C transmission through micro controller but still i have a doubt on certain things.

First being, if we send a data like 0x0a, then we can monitor the data as it is a single byte data.
But when the data becomes multiple bytes  like a float/integer (4 Byte/2 Byte), how can we debug whether correct data is coming or not, if we are watching through a scope?
I am sure we have to look up through the scope, but i heard compiler transmits data type in to binary for both integer and float.  I have looked up at single point precision for float and got some idea.

What is the method to check the integer/float data coming is correct through scope?

Comment: You would be much better off to use a logic analyzer, or better yet a debugger or ICE.

Comment: Ok..I am using pic controller.Microchip have similar things..You think it is better to check with Debugger/analyzer than scope?

Comment: If you're more than a few bytes at a time, it will be a nightmare to debut I2C on a scope. And you really shouldn't accept an answer an hour after you ask the question. Give people in other time zones a chance to answer.

Comment: @MattYoung, While I agree that having a logic analyzer would be far better, I interpreted the meat of Rookie91's question as asking more about what the underlying format of these data types were rather than the method by which he could observe them. If you don't know what the format should be then having a debugger or logic analyzer would still not help you in determining if what you are sending is correct. Thus, I gave an answer that I thought would be most helpful in that regard and perhaps it was appropriate in this case for Rookie91 to select an answer at that point.

Comment: @JonL I'm only saying use the right tool for the job. In debugging, if you don't know what your expected values should be, then you have much bigger problems, and I'm not touching that.

Comment: Im sorry @MattYoung i was bit hesitant.No my point of question was that..in which format the integer/float is send in i2c..if i store a number 9 as integer and send it via i2c.how will be the data shown?..as it will take 2 bytes in the c18 compiler.Yes i understand the importance of debugger/analyzer..but i just asked due to curiosity

Comment: @Rookie91 I should have just voted to close since you don't seem to have taken the time to understand the I2C protocol, or know your expected values. I don't see how your accepted answer is of any use to you.

Comment: Using an ICD the function of any data stream can be checked by reading the values sent to the transmitting UART and the values read from the receiving UART. If they are the same it works. Simple!... of course if it's not the same you have a problem. The byte format for non integer numbers is compiler/convention specific. It's in the documentaion of the compiler / library .

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the format and size of the data types that are being sent.

The easier example would be the integer. For your system, integers are represented with 2 bytes, or 16-bits (check your compiler documentation for the right size).  You would analyze this on a scope the same way you would analyze sending a single byte, but instead watch for 2 contiguous bytes to reconstruct the integer.  For example, sending the unsigned integer 3241 should show 0xA9 * 0x0C * - where each '*' is a slave acknowledge (order of bytes may be reversed depending on endianess).

Here is a wikipedia entry on a [IEEE single precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format).  If you are sending a float, expect to see the bytes being sent to be in this format.

This answer is assuming that you are actually sending each byte of the intended variable, not just the first one.  If you are passing a byte pointer or buffer to your I2C methods along with a size, ensure that you are pointing to the variable and passing the correct size with the sizeof operator.

Comment: Thank u very much .well my compiler is c18 and it takes 2bytes for int and 4 bytes for float.Is it important that you start with first byte or last byte?..i trust some one will handle the order..or is it troublesome?

Comment: The size of `int` is platform specific, and the 32 bit thing is mostly a function of the fact that most desktop PCs have been 32 bit for quite a while. It is by no means a standard, though. `int` in AVR-GCC is 16-bit, for example. Furthermore, "Integer" is not a specific size at all, and I'd take issue with you "most" statement. There are probably more 8-bit embedded MCUs in the world then all other CPU types combined.

Comment: @ConnorWolf, I checked the C18 spec and it is indeed 16-bit.  I'll make the change, thanks.

Comment: The I2C spec only speaks in terms of bytes. Any "meaning" of a sequence of bytes (e.g. larger integers, floats, strings, etc.) is up to the master and slave to agree upon.